# Strange issue with Litespeed Wordpress cache plugin (LSCWP) and Mixpanel Initial Referrer property

Tags: wordpress, mixpanel, litespeed

We use Mixpanel events on our Wordpress/Woocommerce store to track where our customers are originiating using UTM properties and so on and we are noticing some slightly strange differences in the data between when our caching plugin (Litespeed LSCWP Caching plugin) is switched on and when it is off.

The issue is clearly shown by the Mixpanel report here:

[image]

I have an event called `page-view` that fires as you'd expect on every page view. The graph shows `page-view` events where the initial referrer is OUR OWN site - on the first visit. And the peaks are when Litespeed is active, the troughs are when it is off. Our overall daily count of `page-view` events is around 2K so as a percentage, this affects 10-15% of new visits when Litespeed is on and 2% when Litespeed is off.

It seems counter intuitive that the Initial Referring domain is our own site on the first visit for customer, because if that was the case, then surely it wouldn't be counted as the first visit. But more importantly why does this differ so greatly with Litespeed caching?

My initial thought was that visitors are arriving at a page and leaving before the `page-view` event fires, their `document.referrer` is set to our site, but the `page-view` event only fires for the first time on the second page. In my Litespeed plugin Page Optimization settings I have turned off Load JS Deferred to try and ensure the `page-view` event fires as early possible, but this has had no effect on the graph. The only thing that works is disabling Litespeed plugin entirely - but obviously I don't want to do that because of the speed gains.

It's probably a long shot - but if anyone has any thoughts about why this might be happening, I'd appreciate it.